# JAVACC How to pass token for 1 or more

Tags: parsing, lexer, bnf, javacc

I have started learning javacc parser recently. I was requested to write a parser in which a token takes numbers from 1 to many and another token which take numbers from 2 to many
Therefore I came up with something like this:

```
TOKEN : {
<NUM1: <NUM> (<NUM>)* > //for one or more
<NUM2: (<NUM>)+> //for two or more
<NUM :(["0"-"9"])+>





 // and in the function
    void calc():
    {}
    {
     (
      (<NUM1>)+
     (<NUM2>)+
     )* <EOF>
    }
```

However even if I pass a text value WITH no numbers, it is getting passed successfully. What am i doing wrong in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaCC syntax for the lexical tokens allows you to have repetitions of elements enclosed in a scope `()` followed by one of:

```
? - zero or one time
* - zero or more times
+ - one or more times
```

In your case, you need two tokens:

```
TOKEN: 
{
  <NUM2: ["0"-"9"] (["0"-"9"])+> // for two or more
  <NUM1:           (["0"-"9"])+> // for one or more
}
```

You read that as:

- token named `NUM1` matches from one to infinity number of digits
- token named `NUM2` matches from two to infinity number of digits

The lexical machinery in JavaCC consumes one character from the input character stream and attempts to recognize a token. The two automata are as follows:

[image: Lexer Automata]

The **lexer** progresses simultaneously in the both automata for the both tokens. After no more progress is possible the **latest** found token is recognized. If **more the one** token type is possible, then the one declared **first** is recognized. For this reason `NUM2` is declared before `NUM1`. This means that for input `1` the token `NUM2` is **not** going to be recognized, because more then one digit is needed for it. In this case `NUM1` is going to be the only one token type that matches this input. For input `12` both token types are going to accept it, but `NUM2` is going to be recognized, because its declared first. This means that if you order them `NUM1` first, then `NUM2` you are never going to receive `NUM2` token, because `NUM1` will always "win" with its highest precedence.

To use them, you can have two parser functions like these:

```
void match_one_to_many_numbers() : {} { <NUM1> (" " <NUM1>)* <EOF> }
void match_two_to_many_numbers() : {} { <NUM2> (" " <NUM2>)* <EOF> }
```

You read that as:

- function `match_one_to_many_numbers` accepts from **one** to **infinity** number of token `NUM1`, delimited by a space, and then the input stream have to end with the `EOF` system token
- function `match_two_to_many_numbers` the same, just from token `NUM2`

Because both of the tokens accept infinite number of digits, you cannot have a sequence of these tokens without a delimiter that is not a digit.

Comment: Since `<NUM1>` only matches tokens that contain one digit you could write simply `<NUM1: (["0"-"9"])>`. If you want to match a token that has 1 or more digits, you can write `(<NUM1> | <NUM2>)` in the parser.

Comment: The use of `" "` in the parser only makes sense if you have a `TOKEN` declaration such as `TOKEN:{ <SPACE : " ">}`. If you are skipping space with, say, `SKIP:{< " ">}`, then you don't need to, and shouldn't, use " " in the grammar.  If there is no TOKEN or SKIP declaration for `" "`, and you use `" "` in the grammar rules, then JavaCC will infer a `TOKEN` declaration for you, which might not want. Read the documentation and the FAQ for a full explanation.

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell The first comment is not true, the second one is unrelated to the question (there is nothing preventing one to use inline token declarations inside the parser grammar, it is a documented feature, I have kept the two token types as requested in the question, without other irrelevant tokens).

Comment: The first comment contained three assertions. Which isn't true? (a) Strings of more than one digit will not result in NUM1 tokens. (b) Therefore, the definition of NUM1 can be simplified. (c) You can match strings of 1 or more digits as shown.

The second comment was intended to clarify your use of " " for the questioner.  There was nothing in his question that indicated that he wanted " " to be a token. So I thought it worth pointing out that your grammar makes " " a token, which is something that might not be obvious to a beginner.

Comment: a) `NUM1` does not match only one digit, as it is the question, and for this reason it cannot be simplified. b) you cannot match characters in the parser grammar, you only match tokens. If you have `(<NUM1> | <NUM2>)` in the parser grammar you do match one of two tokens, not one token.

Comment: Nothing in the question prevents me to declare inline tokens in the parser grammar, and I did that intentionally to avoid more explicitly declared tokens and keep them as requested: only two. You are right that `" "` is an inline token, but I respectfully disagree that one should not use them, because for this use case they pass perfectly to the need.

Comment: I was reffering to `NUM1` as you defined it and in the context in which you defined it. Strings of more than one digit will be matched as a `NUM2` leaving only strings of one digit to be matched as a `NUM1`. I'm sure you know that, as you explained the mechanism in your answer.

Comment: Yes. Nothing prevents you from defining `" "` as a token. What I said is that if the OP wanted to skip spaces, then they should not define `" "` as a token.

Comment: @NikolayHandzhiyski BPlease understand that I was not correcting anything that you said and that I was not trying to educate you about anything. I was explaining two of the subtler aspects for the original poster's benefit.

Comment: Referring to @NikolayHandzhiyski 's comment of Oct 8 19:17. If you pick one of two deserts, you are still only getting one desert.

Comment: I still disagree :) on both. The question was that one of the tokens can be made of one or more digits. That this token is not going to ever have more then one digit (because it will be "overwritten" by another token) is for me is not important, and is an optimization that the user might or might not want. Its a meter of opinion.

Comment: On the two tokens match, it depends what you call a token. One is the defined in the grammar in the section `TOKEN`: like token type. That is what I have assumed. If you mean a token at runtime: like token instance, then yes you can use that to match a token instance that has one of the two token types. I guess it is a misunderstanding. Please give a second answer if you like.